# Classification of normal operator in hermitian and Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra

An operator $f:V\to V$ on hermitian (euclidean) space is called normal if $ff^*=f^*f$.

**Theorem:** Let $f:V\to V$ be an operator on hermitian space. $f$ is normal **iff** there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

This is a well-known theorem. But I guess that this theorem fails in the case of Euclidean space.

$\Leftarrow$ This direction is ALWAYS true obviously.

$\Rightarrow$ this direction I guess is wrong. Suppose an operator $f$ in some orthonormal basis is given by the following matrix $$A_f=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This operator is normal but there is no orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

*Normality:* Easy to check that $A_f^*=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_{ff^*}=A_{f^*f}$ so it follows that $ff^*=f^*f$.

If there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors say $\{e'_1,e'_2\}$ i.e. $f(e'_1)=\alpha e'_1, f(e'_2)=\beta e'_2$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of its characteristic polynomial $t^2+1$ which is wrong.

Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, what is an hermitian space?

Comment: @Azif00, vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with sesquilinear positive definite form.

Comment: @ZFR: Yes, you are right. An operator on an Hermitian space is orthogonally diagonalizable iff it is normal. An operator on an Euclidean space is orthogonally diagonalizable iff it is self-adjoint. Since a self-adjoint operator is normal (but not the other way around), this means that if an operator is orthogonally diagonalizable, it is normal but the other direction doesn't work over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @levap, Thanks a lot!